# UNIX wc -l with line length restriction

Tags: shell, unix, lines, wc

I need to count the number of lines in a file, in a UNIX shell script, but I need the number of lines under 80 characters, and if there are more than 80 characters, count it as multiple lines.

I know wc -l counts the number of lines, and I know there aren't any options to specify this kind of thing, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [fold](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fold) to break lines > 80 characters and then pipe the output to [wc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc), e.g.

```
$ fold file | wc -l
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 1):

This may do what you want:

```
sed -r 's,(.{80}),\1\n,g' filename | wc -l
```

Comment: You don't need a capture group. `sed -r 's/.{80}/&\n/g'`

Answer (score 0):

While the `fold` answer best fits the unix way:

```
awk '{n += 1+int(length/80)} END {print n}' filename
```